# Stopping Threads - getting invalid thread id

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

This question has been answered before and I'm trying to implement the second solution in the [first answer outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) (NB: the first solution does not concern me, my thread is running a server from an external library and can't be modified to check a flag)

I've tried to implement the simplest case that corresponds to my circumstances. I have a class that spawns a thread and that thread should be stopped externally (the thread never finishes naturally, as in this example). **NB: `_async_raise` and `ThreadWithExc` are copy/pastes of the accepted answer to this question on SO**:

```
import threading
import inspect
import ctypes
import time

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python
def _async_raise(tid, exctype):
    if not inspect.isclass(exctype):
        raise TypeError("Only types can be raised (not instances)")
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid,
                                                  ctypes.py_object(exctype))
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("invalid thread id")
    elif res != 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, 0)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python
class ThreadWithExc(threading.Thread):
    def _get_my_tid(self):

        if not self.isAlive():
            raise threading.ThreadError("the thread is not active")

        if hasattr(self, "_thread_id"):
            return self._thread_id

        for tid, tobj in threading._active.items():
            if tobj is self:
                self._thread_id = tid
                return tid

        raise AssertionError("could not determine the thread's id")

    def raiseExc(self, exctype):
        _async_raise( self._get_my_tid(), exctype )

def work():
    while True:
        print('work')
        time.sleep(1)

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = ThreadWithExc(target=work)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        _async_raise(self.thread.raiseExc(TypeError))


server = Server()
server.start()
server.stop()
```

This gives a `ValueError: invalid thread id` exception. I also tried `threading.get_ident()` instead of the answer's `_get_my_tid()`; that gives me another ID but that one is also invalid.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fundamental problem you have is that you're not calling `_async_raise()` correctly and should replace the line:

```
_async_raise(self.thread.raiseExc(TypeError))
```

in `Server.stop()` with:

```
self.thread.raiseExc(TypeError)
```

If you do just that, however, you'll get an `Exception in thread Thread-1:` because there's no exception handler in the `work()` function to handle the exception that gets raised by `raiseExc()`.

The following fixes that and uses a custom Exception subclass to make things more clear:

```
import threading
import inspect
import ctypes
import time

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python
def _async_raise(tid, exctype):
    if not inspect.isclass(exctype):
        raise TypeError("Only types can be raised (not instances)")
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid,
                                                  ctypes.py_object(exctype))
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError("invalid thread id")
    elif res != 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, 0)
        raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python
class ThreadWithExc(threading.Thread):
    def _get_my_tid(self):

        if not self.isAlive():
            raise threading.ThreadError("the thread is not active")

        if hasattr(self, "_thread_id"):
            return self._thread_id

        for tid, tobj in threading._active.items():
            if tobj is self:
                self._thread_id = tid
                return tid

        raise AssertionError("could not determine the thread's id")

    def raiseExc(self, exctype):
        _async_raise(self._get_my_tid(), exctype )

def work():
    try:
        while True:
            print('work')
            time.sleep(1)
    except Server.ThreadStopped:
        pass

    print('exiting work() function')

class Server:
    class ThreadStopped(Exception): pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = ThreadWithExc(target=work)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
#        _async_raise(self.thread.raiseExc(TypeError))
        self.thread.raiseExc(self.ThreadStopped)

server = Server()
server.start()
server.stop()
```

Output:

```
work
exiting work() function
```

Comment: I tried copy-pasting your example and I'm still getting `ValueError: invalid thread id` (python3.6 - macOS)

Comment: I'm also getting the same error on python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: @Juicy: Sorry can't reproduce your problem and the posted code works for me on Windows 7 with Python 3.6.1.

Comment: @Juicy: I just read a comment on the related ActiveState recipe that says in the `_async_raise()` function to use `res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(tid), ctypes.py_object(exctype))` to wrap tid as `ctypes.c_long`. Do same for the other call in the function, too.

Comment: @Juicy: Since you accepted my answer, should I assume wrapping the `tid` with `ctypes.c_long(tid‌​)` made it start working for you? I would like to know so I can up the posted code (because it still works for me that way, too).

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work on Linux/macOS even with you suggested edit.

Comment: @Juicy: Thanks for the response. Are you using a 32- or 64-bit version of Python? That might affect the type if arguments the `pythonapi` functions expect—so the argument may need to be wrapped in something else (like `ctypes.c_longlong`. Note I'm using the 32-bit version of 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6:

```
self._thread_id = ctypes.c_long(tid)
```

Python 3.7:

```
self._thread_id = ctypes.c_ulong(tid)
```